DataFrame that is a partial view
Is it possible to create a dataframe where one fragment is a view of another df and the remaining fragment is not a view?
I am unable to create such a df, but I want to know if it is possible.
If this is possible, can you give an example of such a dataframe?

My advice: don't. It's very risky, you can create such arrays but they're not always reliable. It depends how you modify data. Better use two separate DataFrames, or save the indices to modify.

I think you can make something like this when you construct the dataframe with copy=False parameter. Consider this:
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])

df1 = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=["a1", "b1", "c1"], copy=False)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=["a2", "b2", "c2"], copy=False)
df2["d"] = 999

print(df1)
print(df2)

This prints:
   a1  b1  c1
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6

   a2  b2  c2    d
0   1   2   3  999
1   4   5   6  999


Now when you do:
df1.loc[0, :] = -1

print(df1)
print(df2)

This prints:
   a1  b1  c1
0  -1  -1  -1
1   4   5   6

   a2  b2  c2    d
0  -1  -1  -1  999
1   4   5   6  999


That's nice, but as commented to the question, quite risky. If you change the dtype this will break the view. Ex. df1.loc[0, 'b1'] = 'X' ; df1.loc[1, :] = -1
